# Starting Scripts Using SSH

Tags: shell, script

Case 1:

```
./Myscript.sh param   (on a first node)
```

Another node: (In parallel i run the same script)

```
./Myscript.sh param   (on a second node)
```

Case2:

From my host, using ssh:

```
for i in $(seq $nb_lignes)

 do
    machine=`head $1 -n $i | tail -1`
    echo "[Node is ] "
    echo $machine

    ssh root@$machine -x "./Myscript.sh param"  &

done
```

I'd like to know what's the difference between these two cases ?
Thank you so much for explanations
Kind regards.

Comment: Do you have a key for ssh connection between your host and the nodes?